# DB Concurrency Exception when adding ranges to a list

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following two tables

```
Datalog | SerialNumber, SignalId (FK), DatalogId
DatalogData | Datetime, Value, DatalogId (FK)
```

Each Datalog can have multiple DatalogData-Entries. So the Datalog Table is already filled with values, now I need to fill in the DatalogData table, here it fails and I can't figure out why. The whole setup is a webapi tool

So here is the method, that takes new DatalogData Values and should fill in the table

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/logger/{serialNumber}")]
public IHttpActionResult PutLoggerData(string SerialNumber, [FromBody] LogViewModel LogViewModel)
{
    List<Datalog> Datalogs = db.Datalogs.Where(s => s.SerialNumber == SerialNumber).ToList();
    foreach (Datalog dl in Datalogs)
    {
        db.DatalogDatas.AddRange(LogViewModel.GetList(
        LogViewModel.names.IndexOf(dl.Signal.Name)).Select(s => new DatalogData()
        {
            Datetime = s.Item1,
            Value = s.Item2,
            Datalog = dl
        }));
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Ok("ok");
}
```

The LogViewModel looks like this

```
public class LogViewModel
{
    public double[][] val;
    public List<string> names;
    public List<double> time;

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<System.DateTime, double>> GetList(int SignalCol)
    {
        List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> Set = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
        for (int i=0; i<val.Length;i++)
        {
            Set.Add(Tuple.Create(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(time[i]).ToLocalTime(),
                val[i][SignalCol]));
        }
        return Set;
    }
}
```

When I debug, the foreach loop in the main method works for the first iteration, the second gives me a `DB Concurrency Exception`, I don't understand why.

**UPDATE**

Do maybe the DB design is crucial here. The DatalogDatas should not have any dupicates, so it has no primary key but an unique index on `Datetime` and `DatalogId`. The table Datalog has a PK on `DatalogId` and an unique index on `SerialNumber` and `SignalId`.

Comment: try to use 
    db.SaveChanges();
after loop.

Comment: Same thing, the first iteration gets written, all others don't

Comment: There is a "{" missing in the first code block, right after the method signature. Maybe you forgot a part?

Comment: Only comments I removed, no working code. I added the missing {

Comment: I assume you configured concurrency tokens? If so, what are they?

Comment: Do you have inner exception?

Comment: @GertArnold I use DBfirst, some additional information are added in the question

Comment: @garret Inner exception is null

Comment: So I guess `Datetime` and `DatalogId` are configured as primary key in EF? (Since EF always needs a primary key).

Comment: No, they were configured as unique index. I now changed the DB such, that I added a new pk and removed the index. No it works.... But nevertheless, I would like to have an index :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, well actually two mistakes

1. The JSON data was not proper, meaning, the time vector somehow got corrupted. I switched from timestamp to string, now it works
2. Since the time vector had identical (falsely) values, ofc the index ignored those `INSERT` commands
3. I forgot that EF requires a Primary Key

Thanks to all for the effort